# Extracting nth position from space-separated string in dplyr

Tags: r, string, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
data <- data.frame(label = c('S', 'SH', 'S', 'S', 'SH'),
               word = c('sip', 'shoe', 'plaster', 'reception', 'reception'),
               word.segs = c('S IH1 P', 'SH UW1', 'P L AE1 S T AH0', 'R AH0 S EH1 P SH AH0 N', 'R AH0 S EH1 P SH AH0 N'),
               seg.index = c(1, 1, 4, 3, 6))
```

'word.segs' contains a phonetic transcription of the words in the 'word' column, and the value in 'seg.index' refers to the segment of interest - the nth segment in that transcription. What I want to do is to create two new columns containing the two segments *after* this, i.e. seg.index+1 and seg.index+2.

I've tried it in the following loop, which works but it takes absolutely ages (and I have 100k rows, so it's important to have an efficient solution here)

```
for (x in 1:nrow(data)){
  data[x, ]$fol.seg = unlist(data$word.segs[x])[data[x, ]$seg.index+1]
  data[x, ]$fol.seg2 = unlist(data$word.segs[x])[data[x, ]$seg.index+2]
}
```

(note that I've also tried only unlisting once, saving this to a separate object and then extracting the two values of interest, but this doesn't appear to be significantly faster)

I also tried an alternative in dplyr in the hope that it might be more efficient:

```
data <- data %>%
  mutate(fol.seg = word.segs %>%
  strsplit(split = " ") %>%
  unlist() %>%
  nth(seg.index+1))
```

But I get the following error message, and I have no idea why it's not working:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>     Evaluation error: length(n) == 1 is not TRUE.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, just using base R. You might be able to fancy it up with `purrr`.

```
library(dplyr)

try_pull = function(x, i) {
  if (i > length(x)) NA else x[[i]]
}

res = data %>%
  mutate(seg_list = strsplit(word.segs, split = " "),
         seg1 = Map(f = try_pull, seg_list, seg.index + 1),
         seg2 = Map(f = try_pull, seg_list, seg.index + 2)
  )
res
#   label      word              word.segs seg.index                      seg_list seg1 seg2
# 1     S       sip                S IH1 P         1                     S, IH1, P  IH1    P
# 2    SH      shoe                 SH UW1         1                       SH, UW1  UW1   NA
# 3     S   plaster        P L AE1 S T AH0         4          P, L, AE1, S, T, AH0    T  AH0
# 4     S reception R AH0 S EH1 P SH AH0 N         3 R, AH0, S, EH1, P, SH, AH0, N  EH1    P
# 5    SH reception R AH0 S EH1 P SH AH0 N         6 R, AH0, S, EH1, P, SH, AH0, N  AH0    N
```

Comment: Works perfectly - thanks! (although 'pattern' is throwing an error, I think it's 'split' instead?)

Comment: Ah yes, I was initially using `stringr::str_split` which has a pattern argument, forget to switch it to `split` when I switched to `strsplit`.

Answer (score 1):

A different `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
data %>%
 rowwise() %>%
 mutate(seg1 = sapply(strsplit(as.character(word.segs), " "), function(x) x[seg.index + 1]),
        seg2 = sapply(strsplit(as.character(word.segs), " "), function(x) x[seg.index + 2]))

  label word      word.segs              seg.index seg1  seg2 
  <fct> <fct>     <fct>                      <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1 S     sip       S IH1 P                        1 IH1   P    
2 SH    shoe      SH UW1                         1 UW1   <NA> 
3 S     plaster   P L AE1 S T AH0                4 T     AH0  
4 S     reception R AH0 S EH1 P SH AH0 N         3 EH1   P    
5 SH    reception R AH0 S EH1 P SH AH0 N         6 AH0   N
```

Here, it splits the "word.segs" by `strsplit()` and then selects the desired elements using `sapply()`.

Or using the idea from your original post:

```
data %>%
 rowwise %>%
 mutate(seg1 = strsplit(as.character(word.segs), " ") %>%
         unlist() %>%
         nth(seg.index + 1),
        seg2 = strsplit(as.character(word.segs), " ") %>%
         unlist() %>%
         nth(seg.index + 2))
```

Comment: Ahh I was so close with the second solution - thanks for correcting it! If anyone is wondering, the sapply() solution takes 11.93s and the unlist() solution takes 39.13s (for the full dataset of 100k rows, that is)

Answer (score 0):

The following data.table approach should be both fast and flexible to select all segs after seg.index or just the first two

```
library(data.table)
data <- data.frame(label = c('S', 'SH', 'S', 'S', 'SH'),
                   word = c('sip', 'shoe', 'plaster', 'reception', 'reception'),
                   word.segs = c('S IH1 P', 'SH UW1', 'P L AE1 S T AH0', 'R AH0 S EH1 P SH AH0 N', 'R AH0 S EH1 P SH AH0 N'),
                   seg.index = c(1, 1, 4, 3, 6),stringsAsFactors = F)
data$id <- 1:nrow(data)

dt <- as.data.table(data,stringsAsFactors=F)
setkeyv(dt,"id")

segdt<-dt[,list(seg.index=seg.index,seg=unlist(strsplit(word.segs,"\\s+"))),by="id"][,n:=1:.N,by="id"]

segdt<-segdt[n>seg.index][,`:=`(seg.col=paste0("seg",1:.N),seg.num=1:.N),by="id"]
#dt[segdt[,list(index.word.segs=paste(seg,collapse=",")),by="id"]] #rejoin original table and all segs after seg.index

widesegs <- dcast.data.table(segdt[seg.num<=2,.(id,seg,seg.col)],id ~ seg.col,value.var="seg") #only first two segs after seg.index or NA

dt[widesegs]
```

Results:

```
> dt[widesegs]
   label      word              word.segs seg.index id seg1 seg2
1:     S       sip                S IH1 P         1  1  IH1    P
2:    SH      shoe                 SH UW1         1  2  UW1   NA
3:     S   plaster        P L AE1 S T AH0         4  3    T  AH0
4:     S reception R AH0 S EH1 P SH AH0 N         3  4  EH1    P
5:    SH reception R AH0 S EH1 P SH AH0 N         6  5  AH0    N
```

#### Alternative Results:

To keep all segments greater than seg.index:

```
widesegs <- dcast.data.table(segdt[,.(id,seg,seg.col)],id ~ seg.col,value.var="seg") #all segs after seg.index or NA

dt[widesegs]
> dt[widesegs]
   label      word              word.segs seg.index id seg1 seg2 seg3 seg4 seg5
1:     S       sip                S IH1 P         1  1  IH1    P   NA   NA   NA
2:    SH      shoe                 SH UW1         1  2  UW1   NA   NA   NA   NA
3:     S   plaster        P L AE1 S T AH0         4  3    T  AH0   NA   NA   NA
4:     S reception R AH0 S EH1 P SH AH0 N         3  4  EH1    P   SH  AH0    N
5:    SH reception R AH0 S EH1 P SH AH0 N         6  5  AH0    N   NA   NA   NA
```

Comment: Ah that solution with all of the subsequent segments is good to know - I hadn't thought of using a data.table. Thanks!